# Error in using the predict() function

Tags: r, predict

Shall I convert the output of `ar.ols` to be some type that `predict` can accept?

```
y=rnorm(100, 0,1)
z=rnorm(100, 0,1)
yz=cbind(y,z)
> output = ar.ols(yz, aic = F, order.max = 2, demean = F, intercept = T)    
> predict(output, n.ahead = 2, se.fit = F)

x=as.data.frame(yz) # x is a data frame, and otherwise same as yz. 
> output = ar.ols(x, aic = F, order.max = 2, demean = F, intercept = T)    
> predict(output, n.ahead = 2, se.fit = F)
Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: With a reproducible example it would be much more interesting to search for the problem...

Comment: @RStudent: thanks. I follow your hint, and the problem is because x is a data frame. Replacing x with as.matrix(x), the problem is gone. I wonder why

Comment: It has to do with how predict.ar is reconstructing the data that was supplied to `ar.ols`. The code seems a little odd to me, but my general recommendation would be that since the documentation for `ar.ols` says that it should be passed a time series, you should probably pass it a time series object.

Comment: @joran: Thanks! How to convert a matrix or a data frame to a time series object?

Comment: See `?ts`. I wouldn't expect data frames to play nicely with time series functions. Matrices or time series objects are the way to go.

Comment: @Tim did that answer your question or there is something unclear?

Answer (score 13):

So the error is coming from `predict.ar`. If you will run `?predict` you'll see it is a generic function which "*invokes particular methods which depend on the class of the first argument*"

So

```
class(output)
[1] "ar"
```

and

```
methods(predict)
#  [1] predict.ar*                predict.Arima*             predict.arima0*            predict.glm                predict.HoltWinters*      
#  [6] predict.lm                 predict.loess*             predict.mlm*               predict.nls*               predict.poly*             
# [11] predict.ppr*               predict.prcomp*            predict.princomp*          predict.smooth.spline*     predict.smooth.spline.fit*
# [16] predict.StructTS*

#    Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Tells you that we are looking for the first method

Next attempt would be to look for the error message within that method. The previous operation informed us the `predict.ar` is invisible function, so we will need to combine `getAnywhere` and `capture.output` and some regex function in order to look for the error message, though unfortunately that won't work

```
grep("array", capture.output(getAnywhere("predict.ar")))
## integer(0)
```

That means that the error is coming from some other function which runs within `predict.ar`.

(as @hadley mentions) we will need to use `traceback()` in order identify the inner function which causing it

```
predict(output, n.ahead = 2, se.fit = F)
# Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
traceback()
# 6: array(STATS, dims[perm])
# 5: aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm))
# 4: sweep(newdata, 2L, object$x.mean, check.margin = FALSE)
# 3: rbind(sweep(newdata, 2L, object$x.mean, check.margin = FALSE), 
#          matrix(rep.int(0, nser), n.ahead, nser, byrow = TRUE))
# 2: predict.ar(output, n.ahead = 2, se.fit = F)
# 1: predict(output, n.ahead = 2, se.fit = F)
```

This shows us nicely the workflow of our function call:
call `predict` -> identify the class of the object and call the corresponding method `predict.ar` -> `rbind` the pre-allocated matrix (of size `ncol(x)`*`n.ahead`) with mean-centered data using `sweep` -> while mean-centering the data (using `sweep`), transpose some `array` and create a new `array` while the last operation returns the error.

So basically all `sweep` function does is subtracting the mean of `yz` from `yz` (mean-centering- which could be done just by running `scale(yz, scale = FALSE)` so not sure why they using `sweep` in the first place. Maybe for `dmean = FALSE` special case?). In your case you specified `dmean = FALSE` so it removes zeroes from both columns (which is quite unnecessary operation an probably should have been avoided in that case). Compare

```
all.equal(t(t(yz) - colMeans(yz)), sweep(yz, 2L, colMeans(yz)))
## [1] TRUE
```

The only problem is that `sweep` operates on arrays, so it tries to convert your data to an array while specifying the correct dimensions by passing the `dim` attribute from `yz` and create an `array` for further operations, namely something like

```
dims <- dim(yz)
perm <- c(2L, seq_along(dims)[-2L])
array(colMeans(yz), dims[perm])
```

That works fine matrices because all matrices have a `dim` attribute by definition.

Although `data.frame`s don't have a `dim` attribute, the `dim(x)` function is still smart enough to calculate the dim itself, so this works perfectly fine

```
dim(x)
## [1] 100   2
```

The only problem is that the `predict.ar` function strips the `class` attribute from `x` somewhere in the process before it reaches `sweep`, so this is where the difference between the `matrix` and the `data.frame` is significant for that matter

```
class(x) <- NULL
dim(x)
## NULL
class(x)
## [1] "list"
```

While

```
class(yz) <- NULL
dim(yz)
## [1] 100   2
class(yz)
## [1] "matrix"
```

Notice, that `x` just became a `list` with different elements such as vectors and attributes, while the `matrix` kept its original structure thanks to its `dim` attribute, so the `class` function can still identify it's a matrix, while `x` was completely deformed and `class` can't handle it anymore.

If you want to know how `class` works, and what really happened see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052158/in-r-why-is-matrix-a-class-but-a-vector-is-not/24055460#24055460)

Anyway, while this still works

```
STATS <- colMeans(yz)
class(yz) <- NULL
dims <- dim(yz)
perm <- c(2L, seq_along(dims)[-2L])
array(STATS, dims[perm])
```

This now returns you the error you saw before

```
x <- as.data.frame(yz)
STATS <- colMeans(x)
class(x) <- NULL
dims <- dim(x)
perm <- c(2L, seq_along(dims)[-2L])
array(STATS, dims[perm])
# Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

I'll leave you the pleasure to further dig [in the rabbit hole](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/attrib.c#L1102-L1113) in order to better understand how `dim` works.

---

So in order to conclude this (as mentioned in comments by @joran)- **Please always start by reading the documentation**. If you'll look closely into `?ar.ols`, `x` is supposed to be *A univariate or multivariate time series*. In the examples, `x` is *always* an object of class `ts` and *never* a `data.frame`.

So while I agree that for this specific case when you've specified `demean = FALSE`, this error shouldn't have occurred in the first place, it is still a better practice to know what you are doing. In other words, this is the classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type of a question.

Comment: I think using `traceback()` would get you to the source of the error much faster, and without having to resort to such complex tricks.

Comment: @hadley Thanks, added.