# Why is the class of a vector the class of the elements of the vector and not vector itself?

Tags: r

I don't understand why the class of a vector is the class of the elements of the vector and not vector itself.

```
vector <- c("la", "la", "la")
class(vector) 
## [1] "character"

matrix <- matrix(1:6, ncol=3, nrow=2)
class(matrix) 
## [1] "matrix"
```

Comment: Your "vector" is still of the formal class `vector`.  It is considered a character vector.  See `is.vector(vector)` and `?vector`

Comment: @RichardScriven,I think the actual question here is why `class` acts as he does, i.e., why it returns "matrix" for `matrix` having **any** types of vector in it, while it returns the actual class of the vector when the data stored in a `vector` format

Comment: Gotcha.  Some [good info about vectors and other structures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) explained.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I get from this. `class` is mainly meant for object oriented programming and there are other functions in R which will give you the storage mod of an object (see `?typeof` or `?mode`).

When looking at `?class`

> Many R objects have a class attribute, a character vector giving the
>   names of the classes from which the object inherits. If the object
>   does not have a class attribute, it has an implicit class, "matrix",
>   "array" or the result of mode(x)

It seems like `class` works as follows

1. It first looks for a `$class` attribute
2. If there isn't any, it checks if the object has a `matrix` or an `array` structure by checking the `$dim` attribute (which is not present in a `vector`)

   2.1. if `$dim` contains two entries, it will call it a `matrix`

   2.2. if `$dim` contains one entry or more than two entries, it will call it an `array`

   2.3. if `$dim` is of length 0, it goes to the next step (`mode`)
3. if `$dim` is of length 0 and there is no `$class` attribute, it performs `mode`

So per your example

```
mat <- matrix(rep("la", 3), ncol=1)
vec <- rep("la", 3)
attributes(vec)
# NULL
attributes(mat)
## $dim
## [1] 3 1
```

So you can see that `vec` doesn't contain any attributes whatsoever (see `?c` or `?as.vector` for explanation)

So in first case, `class` performs

```
attributes(vec)$class
# NULL
length(attributes(vec)$dim)
# 0
mode(vec)
## [1] "character"
```

In the second case it checks

```
attributes(mat)$class
# NULL
length(attributes(mat)$dim)
##[1] 2
```

It sees that the object has two dimensions and there for calls it `matrix`

In order to illustrate that both `vec` and `mat` have same storage mode, you can do

```
mode(vec)
## [1] "character"
mode(mat)
## [1] "character"
```

You can also see, for example, same behavior with an array

```
ar <- array(rep("la", 3), c(3, 1)) # two dimensional array
class(ar)
##[1] "matrix"
ar <- array(rep("la", 3), c(3, 1, 1)) # three dimensional array
class(ar)
##[1] "array"
```

So both `array` and `matrix` don't parse a `class` attribute. Let's check, for example, what `data.frame` does.

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep("la", 3))
class(df)
## [1] "data.frame"
```

Where did `class` took it from?

```
attributes(df)    
# $names
# [1] "A"
# 
# $row.names
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $class
# [1] "data.frame"
```

As you can see, `data.fram` sets a `$class` attribute, but this could be changed

```
attributes(df)$class <- NULL
class(df)
## [1] "list"
```

Why `list`? Because `data.frame` don't have a `$dim` attribute (neither a `$class` one, because we just deleted it), thus `class` performs `mode(df)`

```
mode(df)
## [1] "list"
```

Lastly, in order to illustrate how `class` works, we can manually set the `class` to whatever we want and see what it will give us back

```
mat <- structure(mat, class = "vector")
vec <- structure(vec, class = "vector")
class(mat)
## [1] "vector"
class(vec)
## [1] "vector"
```

Answer (score 6):

R needs to know the class of the object you are operating on to perform the appropriate method dispatch on that object. The atomic data type in R is a vector, there is no such thing as a scalar, i.e. R considers a single integer a length one vector; `is.vector( 1L )`.

In order to dispatch the correct method R must know the datatype. It's not much using knowing that something is a vector, when your language is implicitly vectorised and *everything* is designed to operate on a vector.

```
is.vector( list( NULL , NULL ) )
is.vector( NA )
is.vector( "a" )
is.vector( c( 1.0556 , 2L ) )
```

So you can take the return value of `class( 1L )` which is `[1] "integer"` to mean, *I am an atomic vector consisting of type `integer`*.

Despite the fact that under the hood a `matrix` is actually just a vector with two dimension attributes, R must know it is a matrix so that it can operate row-wise or column-wise on the elements of the matrix (or individually on any single subscripted element). After subsetting, you will return a vector of the datatype of the elements in your matrix, which will allow R to dispatch the appropriate method for your data (e.g. performing `sort` on a character vector or a numeric vector);

```c
/* from the underlying C code in /src/main/subset.c....*/
result = allocVector(TYPEOF(x), (R_xlen_t) nrs * (R_xlen_t) ncs)
```

You should also note, that before determining the class of an object, R will always check that it is a first a vector, e.g. in the case of running `is.matrix(x)` on some matrix, `x`, R checks that it is first a vector, and then it checks for dimension attributes. If the dimension attributes is a vector of `INTEGER` data types of `LENGTH` 2 it satisfies the conditions for that object being a matrix (the following code snippet is from *Rinlinedfuns.h* from /src/include/)

```c
INLINE_FUN Rboolean isMatrix(SEXP s)
  495 {
  496     SEXP t;
  497     if (isVector(s)) {
  498    t = getAttrib(s, R_DimSymbol);
  499    /* You are not supposed to be able to assign a non-integer dim,
  500       although this might be possible by misuse of ATTRIB. */
  501    if (TYPEOF(t) == INTSXP && LENGTH(t) == 2)
  502        return TRUE;
  503     }
  504     return FALSE;
  505 }

#  e.g. create an array with height and width....  
a <- array( 1:4 , dim=c(2,2) )

#  this is a matrix!
class(a)
#[1] "matrix"

# And the class of the first column is an atomic vector of type integer....
class(a[,1])
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: Yes, this is great. Good that you brought out/emphasized the fact that `"character"` (for instance) really means "character *vector*". Also good explanation of why matrices deserve their own class.

Answer (score 4):

In the [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects), there are six basic types of vector, one of which is `"character"`. There really isn't a base "vector" type, but six different kinds of vectors that are all base types.

On the other hand, [Matrix](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html) is a type of data structure.

Comment: Then is there a difference between the class of a character vector with one element and the class of a character?
In other words is character vector == character?

Comment: As pointed out in the other answer and comments, it's more a matter of character == character vector. A "scalar" mathematically speaking is represented as a one element vector of the appropriate basic type in R.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best diagram I've found that lays out the class hierarchy used by the `class` function:

[image: rpy2 robjects package]

Although the class names don't correspond exactly with the results of the R `class` function, I believe the hierarchy is basically accurate. The key to your answer is that the `class` function **only gives the root class in the hierarchy**.

You will see that `Vector` is **not** a root class. The root class for your example would be `StrVector`, which corresponds to the `"character"` class, the class for a vector with character elements. In contrast, `Matrix` is itself a root class; hence, its class is `"matrix"`.