# Why is there a difference between length(f) and length(g) in this example?

Tags: r

```
f <- function() 1
g <- function() 2
class(g) <- "function"
class(f)  ## "function"
class(g)  ## "function"
length.function <- function(x) "function"
length(f)  ## 1
length(g)  ## "function"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please read [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to get a better understanding of how to phrase your question.  Also please use code tags when sharing code.  You can add these through the editor.

Comment: @Carlise: it doesn't for me (as demonstrated in my edit).  I think this is an interesting puzzle about the internal workings of R.

Comment: This is interesting.  Note that `attr(g, "class")` gives "function" but `attr(f, "class")` gives NULL.

Comment: @Dason, this is simple. These function both don't have a class attribute (prior to `class(g) <- "function"`) so by default, `class` uses `mode` (as per documentation).

Comment: @DavidArenburg I know - I was just saying the problem was interesting to me.  I was just bringing up the `attr` stuff since it might be relevant for why we're seeing what we see.

Comment: @Dason, OK then. Any idea on `length(g)  ## "function"` too? Have no reasonable explanation for this one

Comment: @Dason, you are right. attr(g, "class") gives "function" but attr(f, "class") gives NULL. But class(f) and class(g) return the same result: "function". Could you please give me more information?

Comment: @Bai why did you skip my comment? I gave an explanation there...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Something's going on with the S3 method dispatching distinguishing between an object's class versus their "implicit" class, that seems somewhat subtle to me.

Comment: @BenBolker, I would and I wrote a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052158/in-r-why-is-matrix-a-class-but-a-vector-is-not/24055460#24055460) long ago, but I can't explain `length(g) ## "function"`...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, i am sorry.  you mean that class() cannot return the class name. what kind of situation to use the class() function?

Comment: @Bai I'm saying that when an object doesn't contain a `class` attribute, `class` function uses `mode` by default, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052158/in-r-why-is-matrix-a-class-but-a-vector-is-not/24055460#24055460) on how `class` works. Though I have no idea whats up with `length(g) ## "function"`, this is above my paygrade

Comment: @DavidArenburg. Thanks for your information. Since    length()    is generic. you can define a new method for the generic.    length.function <- function(x)     is the new method.

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed that line there. Then we should probably close this as a dupe

Comment: @Bai, does the answer in the function David linked explain this sufficiently for you, or would further explanation in your specific context be useful?

Comment: I can't explain it, but might be worth noting the difference in the final line of `.Internal(inspect(attributes(g)))` versus `.Internal(inspect(attributes(f)))` for someone that might be able to explain it.  `g` certainly does seem to have an extra `class` attribute which might have triggered dispatch to `length.function`

Answer (score 5):

First, `length` is not a typical generic function, but rather an "[Internal Generic Function](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/InternalMethods)". You can see this by looking at its definition:

```
> length
function (x)  .Primitive("length")
```

Compare this to a typical generic function:

```
> print
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
<bytecode: 0x116ca6f90>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

`length` calls straight into `.Primitive` which then can do dispatch if it does not handle the call itself; the typical approach is directly calling `UseMethod` which only handles dispatch. Also note that there is no `length.default` function because the code in the `.Primitive` call does that:

```
> methods("length")
[1] length.function length.pdf_doc* length.POSIXlt
```

I am not sure it is completely defined when an Internal Generic will look at user defined methods and when it will use only internal ones; I think the general idea is that for a user/package defined (effectively, non-core) class, provided methods will be used. But overriding for internal classes may or may not work.

Additionally (though not strictly relevant for this case), even for a typical generic method, the documentation is ambiguous as to what should happen when the class is derived implicitly rather than given as an attribute. First, what `class()` reports is an amalgamation of things. From the `class` help page:

> Many R objects have a `class` attribute, a character vector giving the names of the classes from which the object *inherits*. If the object does not have a class attribute, it has an implicit class, `"matrix"`, `"array"` or the result of `mode(x)` (except that integer vectors have implicit class `"integer"`).

So despite `class` returning the same thing for `f` and `g`, they are not the same.

```
> attributes(f)
$srcref
function() 1

> attributes(g)
$srcref
function() 2

$class
[1] "function"
```

Now, here is where it gets ambiguous. Method dispatch is talked about in (at least) 2 places: the `class` help page and the `UseMethod` help page. `UseMethod` says:

> When a function calling `UseMethod("fun")` is applied to an object with class attribute `c("first", "second")`, the system searches for a function called `fun.first` and, if it finds it, applies it to the object. If no such function is found a function called `fun.second` is tried. If no class name produces a suitable function, the function `fun.default` is used, if it exists, or an error results.

While `class` says:

> When a generic function fun is applied to an object with class attribute `c("first", "second")`, the system searches for a function called `fun.first` and, if it finds it, applies it to the object. If no such function is found, a function called `fun.second` is tried. If no class name produces a suitable function, the function `fun.default` is used (if it exists). If there is no class attribute, the implicit class is tried, then the default method.

The real difference is in the last sentence that the `class` page has that `UseMethod` doesn't. `UseMethod` does not say what happens if there is no `class` attribute; `class` says that the implicit class is used to dispatch. Your code seems to indicate that what is documented in `class` is not correct, as `length.function` would have been called for `g` were it.

What *really* happens in method dispatch when there is no class attribute will probably require examining the source code as the documentation does not seem to help.