# R-Error in using the sweep function

Tags: r

The code is as follows,

```
> x<-rbind(matrix(rnorm(4,sd=0.3),ncol=2),matrix(rnorm(4,mean=1,sd=0.3),ncol=2))

> ww <- c(4,0)

> x1 <- x[,ww!=0]

> z<-sweep(x1,2,sqrt(ww[ww!=0]),"*")

Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

and the        traceback() shows

```
> traceback()
3: array(STATS, dims[perm])
2: aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm))
1: sweep(x1, 2, sqrt(ww[ww != 0]), "*")
```

So why the error appear and how to fix it?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32172228/3001626) if you really want the "*why*" part.

Comment: I see, I use t(x) instead of x and it runs normally, thx